# How to call userform from button on spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have my initialiser function within the userform "module" but when I go to assign a function to be called from my button, excel doesnt show the userform "module" functions being available.

How can I get my userform to display upon the press of a button from the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

double-click the button you have created and place the call to your macro in the code that displays

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Error: Object Required

Answer (score 1):

You need to cut/paste your code in to a worksheet macro:
1. select and cut your macro
2. double click on sheet1 (Microsoft Excel Objects)
3. paste
4. save
Now you can run your macro

EDIT:
Module if I remember correctly are reserved for OnAction

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily call-up your form on the worksheet without going to VBE, you can simply create a macro (not with `PrivateSub`) with:

```
Sub CommandButton_Click ()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```